# How to logical and values in aggregation?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
db.proxylog.aggregate([{$match:{$and:[{date:"03-10-2016"},{time:$gte:"03:00",$lte:"04:31"}}]}},{$group:{_id:"$ipaddress",totaldatasize: {$sum :"$datasize"}}},{$sort: {totaldatasize:-1}}]);
```

This is the code I tried. But its getting an error.

```
DBObject match1=new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("$and",new BasicDBObject("date","03-10-2016").append("time", new BasicDBObject("$gte","03.00").append("$lte","04.31"))));
DBObject group1=new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id","$ipaddress").append("totaldatasize",new BasicDBObject("$sum","$datasize")));
DBObject sort1=new BasicDBObject("$sort",new BasicDBObject("totaldatasize",-1));
DBObject limit1=new BasicDBObject("$limit",3);
```

AggregationOutput

```
output=table.aggregate(match1,group1,sort1,limit1);
for (DBObject result : output.results()) 
{
  System.out.println("Output is : "+result);
}
```

This is the error message:

> errmsg" : "bad query: BadValue: and needs an array", "code" : 16810

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. You start by showing us what you have tried so far, pointing out where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: DBObject match1=new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("$and",new BasicDBObject("date","03-10-2016").append("time", new BasicDBObject("$gte","03.00").append("$lte","04.31"))));
          DBObject group1=new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id","$ipaddress").append("totaldatasize",new BasicDBObject("$sum","$datasize")));
          DBObject sort1=new BasicDBObject("$sort",new BasicDBObject("totaldatasize",-1));

Comment: this is the code I have tried but its not working. I am not getting any result

Comment: What is your mongo db java driver version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `$match` stage to

```
DBObject match1=new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("$and", Arrays.asList( new BasicDBObject("date","03-10-2016"), new BasicDBObject("time", new BasicDBObject("$gte","03.00").append("$lte","04.31")))));
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code as below and this was worked.

DBObject match1=new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("date","03-10-2016").append("time", new BasicDBObject("$gte","03.00").append("$lte","04.31")));